# How do I view my sidekiq console output locally using the default queue?

Tags: cron, console, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq, worker

I'm using Rails 5.  I would like to create a sidekiq process running locally using the default queue.  My worker class looks roughly like the below ...

```
module Accounting::Workers
  class FileGenerationWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform
      print "starting work ...\n"
      ...
```

I have set up my config/sidekiq.yml file like so, in hopes of running the worker daily at a specific time (11:05 am) ...

```
:concurrency: 20
:queues:
  - default
    ...
:schedule:
  Accounting::Workers::FileGenerationWorker:
    cron: "0 5 11 * *"
    queue: default
```

However, when I start my rails server ("rails s"), I don't see my print statement output to the console or any of the work performed, which tells me my worker isn't running.  What else am I missing in order to get this worker scheduled properly locally?

Answer (score 1):

Run the workers with

```
bundle exec sidekiq
```

You may need to provide the path to the worker module. For example,

```
bundle exec sidekiq -r ./worker.rb
```

Sidekiq by itself doesn't support a `:schedule:` map entry in the [Sidekiq configuration file](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#workers).

[Periodic job](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Scheduled-Jobs#periodic-jobs) functionality is provided in extensions such as [sidekiq-scheduler](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/sidekiq-scheduler/0.4.0).

You need to use classes declared in the [extended `Sidekiq` module](https://github.com/moove-it/sidekiq-scheduler/blob/master/lib/sidekiq-scheduler/extensions/schedule.rb#L4) provided in `sidekiq-scheduler`. For example,

**./worker.rb**

```
require 'sidekiq-scheduler'

require './app/workers/accounting'

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
 config.redis = {db: 1}
end

Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
 config.redis = {db: 1}
end
```

**./app/workers/accounting.rb**

```
module Accounting
   # ...
end

module Accounting::Workers
  class FileGenerationWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker

    def perform
      puts "starting work ...\n"
    end
  end
end
```